# On K-theory of blow-ups of compact complex manifolds

Tags: complex-geometry, kt.k-theory-and-homology

Is there a long exact sequence for the K-theory of (coherent sheaves on) blow-ups of compact complex manifolds? Does it split? What can one say on (possibly, singular) complex analytic spaces here?

Any hints or references would be very welcome!